# How do I remove the last <hr> tag in a foreach loop in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach

I'm making a blog and I've seperated each blog post with a `<hr>` tag. But at the bottom it also loops, because that's how my foreach loops is built.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1>some title</h1>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<hr>
@endforeach
```

That will just output a horizontal line at every bottom of every div. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple logic, you can use [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count) method of collection and compare it to the keys in foreach:

```
@php
  $posts_count = $posts->count();
@endphp

@foreach($posts as $key => $post)
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>some title</h1>
    <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    @if ($key + 1 != $posts_count)
        <hr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works. So there's no way I can replace `$key` with `$post` ? Just to make it shorter. `@if ($post + 1 != $posts_count)`

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it...!!

Answer (score 3):

If i did not missunderstood, this should be the fix

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1>some title</h1>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</div>
 @if ($loop->last)
       <hr>// This is the last iteration.
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: It should not appear after the last entry. Only below the first entry and to the second last entry. So that the last one will not have the <hr> tag. So the opposite of what you suggested, actually.

Comment: i just hope that the idea is clear! you can use $loop variable to work around the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use last-child with CSS.

```
hr:last-child {
display: none;
}
```

But you should specify this in a container, otherwise every last hr on your whole page will be not displayed.

so for example

```
<div id="post-container">
@foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h1>some title</h1>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</div>

<hr>
@endforeach
</div>
```

css

```
#post-container hr:last-child {
display: none;
}
```